# Angular UI Modal Close Method Keypress

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

When you use the [Angular UI modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) and press the Escape key it calls the `dismiss` method.

Is there a way to use the Enter (or Spacebar) key to call the `close` method?

[Here's a starter Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7wqWxipocrBKIt6y63BA?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-keyup="YourFunction($event)"` on modal wrapper. Put id on your modal div: `#modal`. check `event.keyCode` into `YourFunction` and if keycode is 13 (enter) close your modal : `$("#modal").modal('hide');`

Comment: I followed your steps and updated the Plunker. I can't seem to register the keypress (just trying to display an alert). Any idea what I'm doing wrong? http://plnkr.co/edit/L1j3oLLrsDqbzTYhBsc3?p=preview

Comment: I am having the same issue it seems like the key directives doon't work even i am trying with jQuery and no success